# Ricocheting pinball-like shot: Complexity?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, computational-complexity, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Suppose one has $n$ perfect two-sided mirror segments in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.
The segments are open, excluding their endpoints.
They are disjoint as closed segments, i.e., no pair shares an endpoint.

> ***Q***. Given two points $s$ and $t$, what is the computational complexity of
>   deciding whether or not it is possible to shoot a ray from $s$ and
>   hit $t$ by reflection from the mirrors?

---

[image: ReflectionComplexity]

---

All segments endpoints, and $s$ & $t$, have integer coordinates in $[0,N]$, $N=2^L$.
So all coordinates can be represented with $L$ bits.

I've thought about such reflections, but not in terms of computational complexity.
And I do not recall this question being addressed in the literature. But perhaps it
it is implied by more general results...?

Comment: Isn't a question like this considered in ray tracing algorithms?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: Maybe not exactly -- in a typical ray tracing application, $s$ would be given, and the algorithm needs to find all points $t$ for which there is a ray from $s$ to $t$. The given question asks for the complexity of deciding whether a given single point $t$ can be reached by a ray starting at $s$.

Comment: I have a (very!) vague sense that it might be possible to construct ("rig") an NP-hardness proof... I am currently thinking of reduction from [*Set Partition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: Vaguely related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34326/polygonal-billards-programs

Comment: I cannot give an answer to the question, but I can just mention a paper that looks at reflection problems for segments with rational angles: arXiv:1105.2972. In case it can help somehow...

Comment: My intuition tells me that this problem is at least NP-hard and you can probably use a fairly standardized 'gadget' construction to build an appropriate SAT instance (similar to the gadgets for games like Minesweeper etc).